# How can I use python pandas add new columns in specific index

Tags: python, google-maps, csv, pandas

I want to use the Google API to get the "location"s latitude and longitude in CSV file,and I can get 'lat' , 'lng' with the Google API Module. But I can not save the file back to the original file and insert behind "location"

my  original file looks like:

```
date            time     location  birdName count birdName count birdName  count                     
1990-02-10   0900:1200   balabala    bird1    15    bird2    10    bird3    20                   
1990-02-28   1300:1500   balabala    bird4    40    bird5    10    bird6    25       
1990-03-01   0900-1200   balabala    bird7    45    bird8    15    bird9    30                       
  ...          ...         ...        ...    ...     ...     ...    ...    ...
```

And I want to insert the 'lat' and 'lng' columns after 'location',like this:

```
date            time     location   lat   lng  birdName count birdName count birdName  count                     
1990-02-10   0900:1200   balabala   xxx   xxx   bird1    15    bird2    10    bird3    20                   
1990-02-28   1300:1500   balabala   xxx   xxx   bird4    40    bird5    10    bird6    25       
1990-03-01   0900-1200   balabala   xxx   xxx   bird7    45    bird8    15    bird9    30                       
  ...          ...         ...      ...   ...    ...     ...     ...     ...    ...    ...
```

Google API Module:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6SUWnrBmDwSb3BabFdEcXV3LUU&authuser=0

my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
from geocodequery import GeocodeQuery

def addrs(location):
  for addrs in location:
    addr= addrs
    gq = GeocodeQuery("zh-tw", "tw")
    gq.get_geocode(addr)
    lng=gq.get_lng()
    lat=gq.get_lat()
    df['lat']=lat
    df['lng']=lng         
    df.to_csv('./birdsIwant.csv')   


 df = pd.read_csv('./birdsIwant.csv',low_memory=False)
 addrs(df['location'])
```

How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the column order by using fancy indexing:

```
In [179]:
# add the columns
df['lat'] = np.random.randn(len(df))
df['lng'] = np.random.randn(len(df))
df
Out[179]:
         date       time  location birdName  count birdName.1  count.1  \
0  1990-02-10  0900:1200  balabala    bird1     15      bird2       10   
1  1990-02-28  1300:1500  balabala    bird4     40      bird5       10   
2  1990-03-01  0900-1200  balabala    bird7     45      bird8       15   

  birdName.2  count.2       lat       lng  
0      bird3       20 -0.915371 -1.508814  
1      bird6       25 -0.716439  1.008078  
2      bird9       30  0.609510 -1.185927  
In [185]:
# get a list of the columns
col_list = list(df)
# insert column names at new positions
col_list.insert(3,'lat')
col_list.insert(4,'lng')
# slice off the last 2 values
col_list=col_list[:-2]
print(col_list)

['date', 'time', 'location', 'lat', 'lng', 'birdName', 'count', 'birdName.1', 'count.1', 'birdName.2', 'count.2']
In [187]:
# use ix and pass the new column order to sort the order
df = df.ix[:,col_list]
df
Out[187]:
         date       time  location       lat       lng birdName  count  \
0  1990-02-10  0900:1200  balabala -0.915371 -1.508814    bird1     15   
1  1990-02-28  1300:1500  balabala -0.716439  1.008078    bird4     40   
2  1990-03-01  0900-1200  balabala  0.609510 -1.185927    bird7     45   

  birdName.1  count.1 birdName.2  count.2  
0      bird2       10      bird3       20  
1      bird5       10      bird6       25  
2      bird8       15      bird9       30
```

**EDIT**

Your code is writing to csv on every iteration, so even if it did set the correct lat and lng values you're overwriting on each iteration, you should write to csv outside the function. Anyway the following is clearer and should work:

```
def addrs(location):
    gq = GeocodeQuery("zh-tw", "tw")
    gq.get_geocode(location)
    return pd.Series([gq.get_lat(), gq.get_lng()])

df[['lat','lng']] = df['location'].apply(addrs)
df.to_csv('./birdsIwant.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you  and there is a little problem. the data 'lat' and 'lng'  always the last 'locations' after I save the csv file,how can I solve this problem? Please help me again.

Comment: Your code has an error because you're essentially assigning to the your df  the last value on each iteration

Comment: EdChum  ,I ' m sorry to disturb you again. The code you gave will got a new problem. That is "raise URLError(err) URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly >
I change  "df[['lat','lng']] = df['location'].apply(addrs) "   to "df[['lat','lng']] = df['location'][1;300].apply(addrs)",it works. But I want to done it just once , any method to solve?

Comment: Sorry you'll have to research whether there is a query limit with that api, I have no knowledge about that api and if there are limits it'd be difficult to circumvent this, you could just iterate over chunks of your df and process them, by the way index values are zero based so doing `[1:300]` will miss the first row